# Unknown Property when creating a public void

Tags: visualforce, controller, button

When I call the function from a button on a visualforce page using the controller I get

> Unknown Property 'ContractDetails.save'

when I am trying to save the vfp.

Controller:

```
        public class ContractDetails{
            public Opportunity ThisOpportunity{get;set;}  
            public string oppid {get;set;}
            public ContractDetails(){
            oppid = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
            if(oppid==null){
                            oppid = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('oppidd');
       }
            ThisOpportunity = [Select Contract_Requested__c FROM Opportunity where ID=:oppid];
       }
       public void save(){
                    ThisOpportunity.Contract_Requested__c = boolean.valueOf('True');
                    system.debug(ThisOpportunity.Contract_Requested__c);
                    update ThisOpportunity;
       }
```

Button on VFP:

```
<apex:page controller="ContractDetails"  showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false" sidebar="false" docType="html-5.0" >
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <apex:slds />
  <script type="text/javascript">
            function requested(){
                    requestedoper();
                    }
  </script>
  <apex:form id="wf">
  <button class="slds-badge" style="{!requested}" onclick="requested()">Requested</button>
       <apex:actionfunction action="{!save}" name="requesteoper" rerender="wf"></apex:actionfunction></apex:form>
  </html>
  </apex:page>
```

Comment: What you've shared so far isn't enough to identify the cause of your error with any degree of certainty. It sounds to me like you haven't set the `controller` or `extensions` attributes of `<apex:page>` properly, but I can't say for certain unless you share more of your code & visualforce markup. You don't need to share everything, but, at the minimum, seeing the first line(s) of your controller class (i.e. `public class Something{`) and the first line (`<apex:page ...>`) of your visualforce would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use onclick javascript function to call a Controller method. Better from `onclick` function, call javascript function, which in turn call controller method via `actionFunction`.

**Approach 1**

```
<button style="{!requested}" onclick="clickMe()">Requested</button>

<script>
    function clickMe()
    {
        saveOperation();
    }
</script>

<apex:actionFunction action="{!save}" name="saveOperation" rerender="form1"/>
```

**Approach 2**

Directly calling actionFunction also work.

```
<apex:actionFunction action="{!save}" name="saveOperation" rerender="form1"/>
<button onclick="saveOperation()">Requested</button>
```

Comment: D'oh, I saw that OP was using a plain 'ol HTML button, but glossed over that fact when OP was attempting to call an action method. The error the OP was seeing makes sense because in all but a few places, `{!someIdentifier}` tries to reference a property (with an automatic getter, or a method whose name is prefixed with 'get') rather than a 'plain' (action) method. +1 for you.

Comment: OP is confused with property and method with this type of `{!someIdentifier}`

Comment: thanks that worked but I don't think it is calling the function at all, code is updated

Comment: are you getting debug messages in save operation?

Comment: nothing this is the result 13:50:49.0 (16419829)|METHOD_ENTRY|[1]|01p0S000000Di34|ContractDetails.ContractDetails()
13:50:49.0 (16426869)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[1]
13:50:49.0 (16431328)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[1]
13:50:49.0 (16436017)|METHOD_EXIT|[1]|ContractDetails
13:50:49.0 (16702261)|SYSTEM_MODE_ENTER|true
13:50:49.0 (16851241)|SYSTEM_MODE_ENTER|true

Comment: howmany ids you are passing to the page? there are `id`, `oppid`

Comment: correct but depending on how you get to the page it could be "urlhacked" with oppidd or it could be right on the opportunity page where it just would use 'id'

Comment: The sample code I have given is tested and working fine at my DE, there could be other issues at your code. Save button is getting called from both of the approaches which I have provided

Comment: for some reason once i put actionfunction inside of the button endtag it worked